# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: [Ljava.lang.reflect.Method;.myMethod(java.lang.String, boolean)

Tags: java, jboss, stateless

I am trying to get a method from a class using Java 1.7.

The very stranger things is if I print the methodName and its parameters, is the same that I used, but I always get :
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:

Here my code:

```
    public void invokeMethod(String className, String myMethod, List<Object> parametersMethod) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException{
    Class<?> cls = Class.forName(className);

    Method[] allMethods = cls.getDeclaredMethods();
    for(Method m : cls.getDeclaredMethods()){

        Type[] types = m.getParameterTypes();
        String tmp="";

        for (Type type : types) {
            tmp+=type+" ";
        }

        log.info(" " +m.getName()+" "+tmp); // 
    }
    Object obj = cls.newInstance();
    log.info("myMethod "+myMethod);

    Method m= allMethods.getClass().getMethod(myMethod, String.class, boolean.class); 
    log.info("m "+m.getName()+ "  "+m.getParameterTypes()+ "  "+m.getDefaultValue());
    m.invoke(obj, parametersMethod); }
```

Here the method that I am trying to invoke:

```
public void tryIt(String myString, boolean mybool) throws Exception {
       //Do something
}
```

The log.info prints: `tryIt class java.lang.String boolean`

But I get (when I'm trying to use `Method m= allMethods.getClass().getMethod(myMethod, String.class, boolean.class);)`:

> **java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: [Ljava.lang.reflect.Method;.tryIt(java.lang.String, boolean)**

I try with Boolean instead of boolean, but nothing change.

The invokeMethod is on a webservices that use Jboss 7, and all my class are `@StateLess`.

Answer (score 1):

`allMethods` is of type `Method[]`, which has no method `tryIt(String, boolean)`. You want to call `getMethod()` on `cls`

Also you're invoking the method wrong, as `Method.invoke()` expects an array of arguments not a `List`, you probably want a method like this:

```
public void invokeMethod(String className, String myMethod, Object... parametersMethod) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    Class<?> cls = Class.forName(className);

    Object obj = cls.newInstance();

    Method m = cls.getMethod(myMethod, String.class, boolean.class);
    m.invoke(obj, parametersMethod);
}
```

Which can be called like this:

```
invokeMethod("com.example.MyClass", "tryIt", "SomeString", true);
```

Comment: if allMethods as no method tryIt, why the  log.info(" " +m.getName()+" "+tmp); print the method tryit with the correct parameter?

Comment: @LizLamperouge because you're iterating over `cls.getDeclaredMethods()`, but later you're calling an equivalent to this `cls.getDeclaredMethods().getClass().getMethod("tryIt", String.class, boolean.class)`. You want to omit the part `.getDeclaredMethods().getClass()`

Comment: Ok It's work a little.... but not completly, infact if in my method tryIt, I use an EJB like 
@EJB Otherclass otClass.   
public void tryIt(String myString, boolean mybool) throws Exception {
     otClass,doOther();
}

I get a nullPointer.... there is something that I can do?